# Binding an event to a <label> without the event then firing twice

Tags: javascript, html, forms, label, addeventlistener

I have a `<label>` with an `::after` pseudo-element attached to it, to which I would like to bind a `click` event.

```
<label for="my-input">
    <input id="my-input" />
</label>
```

Since pseudo-elements are not part of the DOM, I obviously can't do that, so I have bound the `click` event to the `<label>` instead.

But... we all know what a `<label>` does, right? Yes, it *re-focuses* the cursor on the `<input>`.

So, well done if you've already guessed what happens - **the event fires twice**.

Why? Because it fires once when the user clicks on the `<label>` and *then* the browser auto-clicks on the `<input>` (to re-position the cursor) and that ends up firing the event a second time.

I'd be intrigued to know if there is any creative way around this.

Normally, you'd stop the event firing during the bubbling phase by changing the `useCapture` boolean flag at the end of `.addEventListener()` from `false` to `true` - but in this case that's not going to stop the event (bound to the `<label>`) from firing a second time, when the browser auto-clicks on the `<input>`.

**Working Example:**

```js
var myInput = document.querySelector('label[for="my-input"]');

var clickNumber = 1;

function clickDetected(event) {
    
    console.log('Click ' + clickNumber + ' detected');
    clickNumber++;
}

myInput.addEventListener('click', clickDetected, false);
```

```css
label {
position: relative;
top: 48px;
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
margin: 24px 6px;
padding: 24px;
background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

label[for="my-input"]::after {
content: '+';
position: absolute;
display: block;
top: -26px;
right: 4px;
width: 22px;
height: 22px;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
font-size: 21px;
line-height: 22px;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
border-radius: 2px;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 75, 165, 0.4);
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<label for="my-input">
<input id="my-input" type="text" />
</label>
```

Comment: Why not just add the listener to the input?

Comment: why not put the event on the input and stopPropagation()?

Comment: `event.stopImmediatePropagation();`?

Comment: For what problem is this your attempted solution? (Incidentally, on a tangent, you don't need the `for` attribute on the `<label>` element if the relevant `<input>` is a descendant of the `<label>`.)

Comment: I have a `<label>` with an `::after` pseudo-element attached to it, to which I would like to bind a `click` event. Since pseudo-elements are not part of the DOM, I obviously can't do that.

Comment: But event on :after is still event on label which by default triggers on input

Comment: Hence my question above. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```js
var myInput = document.querySelector('label[for="my-input"]');

var clickNumber = 1;

function clickDetected(e) {


}

myInput.onclick = function (e) {
    if (e.target.getAttribute('id') === 'label') {
    console.log('Click ' + clickNumber + ' detected');
    clickNumber++;
    }
}
```

```css
label {
position: relative;
top: 24px;
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
margin: 24px 6px;
padding: 24px;
background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<label for="my-input" id="label">
<input id="my-input" type="text" />
</label>
```